# Central Limit Theorem - does the number of times the samples are taken matter in terms of the CLT?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

Let's say that in R, we generate $n$ random variables $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ which all follow an exponential distribution. We then construct the mean $\bar{Y_n}$. The process is repeated $m$ times, so we end up with $m$ averages: $\bar{Y_n}^1, \dots , \bar{Y_n}^m$.

The Central Limit Theorem states that the mean will approach a normal distribution as $n$, the sample size, gets larger. What does the Central Limit Theorem say about the size of $m$?

I have tried running it in R, with a fixed (large) value of $n$ and varying $m$, and it seems like the plot approaches normality. I've included two of them here. However, I'm confused since the formula

$$X_n = \frac{\bar{ Y_i} - \mu}{\sigma - \sqrt{n}}$$ doesn't refer to how many times the process is repeated.

So, does the number of times the samples are taken matter in terms of the CLT?

(In case the formatting doesn't work, the plots below show $n=100, m = 50$ and $n=100, m = 500$

[image: m=50]
[image: m=500]

Comment: It's the sampling distribution that becomes normal.  That means the 'real' $m$ is infinite.  However, when you do this as an exercise or a demo, you take a finite $m$ so that you can eventually move on with your day.  Taking a larger $m$ will yield a smoother / prettier plot.

Comment: A slight qualification may be apropos of @gung's remark: for a fixed $n,$ taking $m$ larger and larger will eventually reveal the extent to which the distribution of the mean of $n$ values is *not* Normal (which is almost always the case, except when the underlying data distribution is itself Normal).

Comment: @whuber Thank you both for your answers. I'm a bit confused though; why would a larger $m$ yield a smoother plot (see comment above yours) while at the same time showing the extent to which the mean distribution of $n$ values is not normal???

Comment: Think of the case $n=1.$